# How do I make link the highlight link conform to CSS shape

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How do I make the link outline (blue) conform to the CSS shape? I mean the outline should be in the same shape as the link border.

Would you mind linking, or helping me find the right words to describe it, so I can properly research it, or maybe some basic fixes?

[image]

[image: Link needs to conform to shape]

Comment: You mean with an `outline` property? I don't think you can. Change the `border` instead.

Comment: Is that what it is? A Link Border?

Comment: Please share your code (HTML and CSS) an image doesn't let us identify the issue clearly and suggest appropriate fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `box-shadow` (Hover to see it )

```css
button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  border-radius: 5px 25px 5px 25px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-left:0;
  border-right:0;
  outline: 0;
}
button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px orange;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: I have the button anchored, so for example when you press tab, this is the the blue outline is what is shown, that conforms to the square vs the shape.

Comment: @EricERK I've used `outline:0` that is why the blue line doesn't appear

Comment: It's still appearing for me.

.btn, .btn2, .btn3
{
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 padding:40px 0px;
 color:#fff;
 text-align:center;
 border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.6);
 border-radius: 15px 50px;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 border-top: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 outline: 0;
}

btn's are individually anchored.

Comment: @EricERK You sure you set the `outline:0` on the button and not the `a` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your referring to the outline property. I think this would helps on your problem :)

```
button:focus{
 outline: none;
}
```